# How to open a OSX Terminal Window from Java and execute bash command

Tags: java, bash, macos, terminal

As the title states I have been attempting to spawn a simple OSX terminal window and issue a series of batch commands but to no avail. Here is a summary of a couple things I have tried thus far

1)Firstly I tried the open command:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("open -n -F -a /Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app --args ls");
```

Whilst the preceding code DOES open a terminal window the argument is NOT passed.

2)Next I dropped the "open" command and attempted to execute the terminal app directly passing in the arguments as part of the statement:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal","ls"});
```

Again, this opened the terminal window but the the list files "ls" bash command was not executed.

3)Finally I tried executing the commands directly without specifying the Terminal app:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("ping -c 3 google.com;");
```

Here the reverse was the case the commands ARE executed as specified but the terminal window is NOT displayed it would seem that this method requires that the caller obtains and processes the inputstream from the process in order to see the output produced by the terminal.

Can't think of any further approaches to try at this point to simply open a terminal window and execute a series of batch commands programmatically, any pointers (no pun intended) would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Terminal appears to be designed NOT to be launched from the command line.  See https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mac-os-x/9780596520625/ch01.html for some workarounds and alternatives.

Comment: Simplify the problem: get it to work first without Java and then turn to Java. None of your commands work on the command line either. By posting it as a Java question, you're confusing people as the problem isn't about Java, and you get fewer responses than if you asked the Apple community as a while. On either http://superuser.com or http://apple.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @Jim Garrison. As noted several times in my question, The Runtime exec() method DOES sucessfully launch the Terminal Application the problem is that I can't seem to be able to execute bash commands such as ping or listing files programatically. It would appear that the additional  arguments I pass into the launch command to accomplish these things are being expressly ignored by the spwaned terminal window instance.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt I'm not sure I follow. My question relates SPECIFICALLY to the Java Runtime exec() method. As started I am attempting to use it to launch a terminal window and execute bash commands. Of course, the basic bash commands I utilised in my example work directly in the terminal, for example try typing "ping -c 3 google.com" and you will see it works as expected. My point was I can't seem to get the exec() method execute these bash commands, I've accomplished this numerous times under windows using the cmd.exe appliclication but it doesn't appear to work with the Terminal app under OSX.

Comment: So does NO ONE have any idea how this may be accomplished? Like I say its a relatively trivial thing to do in a windows environment.. But for some reason OSX Terminal just will not accept any arguments on launch... very strange.

Comment: None of your 3 commands work from the command line: neither of them open a new terminal window and execute the given command (most likely because, as Jim mentioned, the Terminal application doesn't offer the functionality to automatically execute the command). But if there is a workaround, you should first get it to work from a terminal. Once you have it working there, it's trivial to do the same from Java.

Comment: I could achieve it via this:
Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(new String[]{"/Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app/Contents/MacOS/Terminal","/bin/ls"});

We just need to give the complete path of command.

PS: We can get the complete path of a command using 'which' command.